# base64 encoding issue

Tags: php, websocket, base64

This is probably an obvious answer but I can't figure it out...

I'm reading this wikipedia entry, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_protocol_handshake and in the example it says the Base64 encoded string of `1d29ab734b0c9585240069a6e4e3e91b61da1969` is `HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=`

Now using the PHP function `base64_encode` I get a different output. I also get a different result on some online base64 encoders! Where the hell is wikipedia getting this base64 value from?

Comment: Different encoding? [What is your output?](http://codepad.org/5UsSuqPq)

Comment: my output of encoding `1d29ab734b0c9585240069a6e4e3e91b61da1969` is `MWQyOWFiNzM0YjBjOTU4NTI0MDA2OWE2ZTRlM2U5MWI2MWRhMTk2OQ==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1d29ab734b0c9585240069a6e4e3e91b61da1969` is the hex string you need to base64 encode the sha1 binary value.

```
<?= base64_encode(pack('H*','1d29ab734b0c9585240069a6e4e3e91b61da1969'))?>
```

http://ideone.com/K0d6y

Answer (score 0):

or you can simply;

```
base64_encode(sha1(<shavalue>,true));
```